# Google Maps Trigger Click Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I create multi marker. When the map has loaded infowindows are closed. I want to open just a marker when the map has loaded. I used `google.maps.event.trigger(markers[2], 'click')` this code but didn't fire anything. How can I do?

```
    function initMap() {
       var center = {lat: <?=$data1[0]['lat']?>, lng: <?=$data1[0]['lng']?>};
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: center
      });   
      <?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
            var myLatLng = {lat:<?=$data1[$i]['lat']?>, lng:<?=$data1[$i]['lng']?>};                    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng, 
                map: map
            });             
   var contentString = "<table style='border-radius:4px; padding:0px;'><tr>"+
       "<td style='width:25%; padding:5px;'><a href='<?=$data1[$i]   ['page_url'];?></td>"+
       "</tr></table>";
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
  }); 
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.open(map,this);
   });
   infowindow.close(map,marker);    
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
   });
   <?php } ?>
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an array of markers (so `markers[2]` doesn't exist)

Comment: How can I choose any marker. I want to click just a marker for to open a infowindow. İt is not important which marker.

Comment: `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')` should click on the last marker created.

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work

Comment: Why the code doesnt work? is there another way?

Comment: I changed some code later worked. Thanks.